# Kendo UI Column Sort

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Can Kendo UI grid sort the column? I want to show the grid column in a certain order. It is dependent on the data binding order.  Can I change it from the code after that?  (not from the rearrange of the column order from the user)

For example: I have a grid shown in column A, B, C. Later on, or for a different user or whatever on some conditions, Column B is more important and I want to rearrange the grid to column B, A, C. I know the user can drag and drop to rearrange it. But I want to do it in code directly. Can I do it?

Or in other way, if every column has an importance factor which is decided in code, how to show the column ordered by its importance factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use grid reorderColumn() method. There is documentation for that method: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-reorderColumn

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.reorderColumn(1, grid.columns[0]);
```